# how can i pass a value to list without using EditorFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view like this, I found that I must use @Html.EditorFor to pass the value to the list, if I use @Html.DisplayFor, the value will not pass, how can i pass the value to the list using something instead of @Html.EditorFor

```
@model IList<TRecord>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // display names area

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(item => item[i].Tid)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(item => item[i].Tname)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    // submit button area
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _without using EditorFor()_? You can use `TextBoxFor()` for example. What is it your wanting to achieve?

Comment: hi dear @Stephen, I want to just display the value item[i].Tid, and I also need to pass the value to the controller ...

Comment: Then use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Tname, new { @readonly = "readonly" })` (or `DisplayFor()` in conjunction with `HiddenFor()`). But what is the point of this - if your not editing the value, then you should not be sending it back (in your POST method, you get the data again and only update the properties you need)

Comment: @Stephen, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that it can't be edited?

If it, try this one.

```
@Html.TextBox(item => item[i].yourObject, new { @readonly = "readonly" } )
```

Comment: That wont even compile. And it certainly wont add the `disabled` attribute. And even if you corrected the code to do so, a disabled form control does not submit a value so its pointless (you may as well use `DisplayFor()`)

Comment: I want to pass the item[i].yourObject to the controller but only display, i don't need to edit, and need to pass to the controller, because when i use EditorFor, it will show a textbox, and i just want to display the value @Farid

Comment: @Farid. Again - disabled controls to not submit a value!

Comment: Thank you, u are so nice ~~

Comment: Glad to help u :D . @StephenMuecke is the real MVP here.